# AWS OpenSearch Serverless PUT results in 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, kibana, opensearch

When using the Dev Tool to PUT data to a newly created index in OpenSearch the response is 404.

> Request failed to get to the server

[image]

I am following the [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html) using timeseries data instead.

```
// Works
PUT analytics-index

// Resolves to 404
PUT analytics-index/_doc/1
{ 
  "foo": "bar",
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to provide the `_id`. according to the screenshot, your are not providing it. You need PUT analytics-index/_doc/1(<-_id)

Comment: I provided the ID as well. I ran this setup in a few variations including `analytics-index/_doc/1`.

Comment: Can you see the index created? Can you share a screenshot maybe with a GET

Comment: Yes, updated the question to include the index.

Comment: Never seen thiese errors you are seeing. Anyways, can you try `DELETE analytics-index` and then do 'PUT analytics-index/_doc {your data}'?

Comment: Deleted and tried PUT commands in a few variations. Behaviour are the same. I guess the questions is what does it mean when 404 is encountered. Does this mean that it's unable to find the index for the PUT command?

Comment: You have shown two screenshots for put, one gives you 404 and the other 400. I am confused. Do you get 404 once and then 400 the second time..?

Comment: 400 when document ID is included and 404 when document ID isn't included.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a time-series collection? In that case,

> For time series collections, you can't index by custom document ID. This operation is reserved for search use cases.

([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless-overview.html#serverless-usecase))

Furthermore, a PUT without a doc id is not currently supported by the API, according to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless-genref.html#serverless-operations)

###### (*Updated on 22.Feb - based on additional comments*)

Comment: That's good to know. But I've tried to PUT without document IDs.

Comment: a PUT without a doc id doesn't seem to be supported though https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless-genref.html#serverless-operations

Comment: If it's not supported then the question would be how does data gets inserted into OpenSearch from Firehose? I am able to create new data via CLI and Firehose through PUT requests.

Comment: that's a different problem, though... i suggest you create a dedicated question for that